# How to decode json, group by a column value, and sum values in each group?

Tags: php, arrays, json, sum

I have data in MySQL. The data is created by json datas. But I can't change to array from data keys. I want to set this data in order and according to the number of stock.

```
[
{"size":"36","stock":"1"},
{"size":"37","stock":"2"},
{"size":"38","stock":"1"},
{"size":"40","stock":"1"},
{"size":"36","stock":"1"},
{"size":"37","stock":"3"},
{"size":"38","stock":"2"},
{"size":"39","stock":"3"},
{"size":"40","stock":"2"}
]
```

I want change to:

```
array(
'36' => '2',
'37' => '5',
'38' => '3',
'39' => '3',
'40' => '3',
)
```

I wrote this function but it only returns `true` and I feel it could be more refined:

```
function shoesizes($json,$key='size')
{
    $array =  json_decode($json);
    $result = array();
    $sum = 0;
    $i=0;
    foreach((array) $array as $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $val)){ 
            $result[$val->$key][] = (array)$val;  
        }else{
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }   
    $arrsi = array(); 
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) { 
        $sum = 0; 
        foreach ($v as $c => $d) { 
            $sum +=     $d['stock']; 
        }
        $arrsi[$k]= $sum; 
    }
    return ksort($arrsi);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode then iterate the array.  If the first occurrence of `size` store the integer value, if not add the new value to the stored value.  When done, sort by the result array keys.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/653cb9cd102d82f54126308a3e2f7f99f7c05ca7))

```
$json = '[
{"size":"36","stock":"1"},
{"size":"37","stock":"2"},
{"size":"38","stock":"1"},
{"size":"40","stock":"1"},
{"size":"36","stock":"1"},
{"size":"37","stock":"3"},
{"size":"38","stock":"2"},
{"size":"39","stock":"3"},
{"size":"40","stock":"2"}
]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (isset($result[$row['size']])) {
        $result[$row['size']] += $row['stock'];
    } else {
        $result[$row['size']] = (int)$row['stock'];
    }
}
ksort($result);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  36 => 2,
  37 => 5,
  38 => 3,
  39 => 3,
  40 => 3,
)
```

---

Code Review:

- `ksort()` returns a boolean result.  By writing `return ksort($arrsi);`, you can only receive `true` or `false` (and `false` can only happen when there is a failure).  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php Once you write `ksort($arrsi);` then `return $arrsi;` then your function returns the desired result.
- You declare, but don't use `$i` so that line can be safely removed.
- The first declaration of `$sum = 0;` isn't necessary because you redeclare the variable later in your second loop.
- Your first loop creates an unnecessarily bloated data structure.  Assigning the `size` values as keys is certainly the right step. Storing each set of date as a subarray of the new key is more than what you need. This causes you to have to follow up with a nested loop.